# VBScript to delete duplicate files with different names and extensions

Tags: vbscript, duplicates

I have searched extensively for a VBscript answer to this, but have given up and need help.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to find obviously duplicate files (obvious to humans, anyway) with different filenames.  I need to delete the duplicates, keeping those WITHOUT the track number in the name.  I also need to delete any M4A versions if I already have it in MP3.

Is this even possible?  I have done a little VBscripting, but this is way over my limited programming ability.  I'm not even going to bother copying here the code that I have tried because none of it is working.

Here's a sample folder I'm trying to clean up.  I want only the two unique songs in here to remain.  I only want the MP3 version, and I don't want the track numbers in their names.

> 07 Falling In Love (Is Hard On The K.mp3
>   1-15 Love In An Elevator.m4a
>   1-15 Love In An Elevator.mp3
>   15 Love In An Elevator.mp3
>   2-07 Falling In Love (Is Hard On The.m4a
>   2-07 Falling In Love (Is Hard On The.mp3
>   Falling In Love (Is Hard On The Knees).mp3
>   Love In An Elevator.mp3

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no simple task, since basically you want measure the similarity/proximity of different file names. My layman approach would be to extract the title from the file name, normalize it, and then use the shortest left-based match for comparing them. Something like this might work:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^\d+(-\d+)?\s+"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADOR.Recordset")
rs.Fields.Append "NormalizedName", 200, 255
rs.Fields.Append "Length", 3
rs.Fields.Append "Path", 200, 255
rs.Open

' Store the full paths of the files and their associated normalized name in
' a disconnected recordset. The "Length" field is used for sorting (see below).
For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\some\folder").Files
  normalizedName = LCase(re.Replace(fso.GetBaseName(f.Name), ""))
  rs.AddNew
  rs("NormalizedName").Value = normalizedName
  rs("Length").Value = Len(normalizedName)
  rs("Path").Value = f.Path
  rs.Update
Next

' sort to ensure that the shortest normalized name always comes first
rs.Sort = "NormalizedName, Length ASC"

ref = ""
Set keeplist = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
  path = rs("Path").Value
  name = rs("NormalizedName").Value
  currentExtension = LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(path))
  If ref <> "" And ref = Left(name, Len(ref)) Then
    ' same title as last file, so check if this one is a better match
    If extension <> "mp3" And currentExtension = "mp3" Then
      ' always pick MP3 version if it exists
      keeplist(ref) = path
      extension = currentExtension
    ElseIf extension = currentExtension _
        And IsNumeric(Left(fso.GetBaseName(keeplist(ref)), 1)) _
        And Not IsNumeric(Left(fso.GetBaseName(path), 1)) Then
      ' prefer file names not starting with a number when they have the
      ' same extension
      keeplist(ref) = path
    End If
  Else
    ' first file or different reference name
    ref = name
    extension = currentExtension
    keeplist.Add ref, path
  End If
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

For Each ref In keeplist
  WScript.Echo keeplist(ref)
Next
```

I'm pretty sure that there are edge cases not covered by the above code, so handle with care. Also note that the code processes only a single folder. For processing a folder tree additional code is required (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/1630171) for instance).

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded sooner, Ansgar, but I never received an email upon someone answering my question as I had requested.  Anyway, THANKS.  I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Wow, that created what looks a great list (keeplist) of the ones I'll want to keep.  I'll work on scripting a deletion routine for the unwanted ones, and let you know.