# A script to move files of certain type to a specified folder

Tags: vbscript, scripting, file-type

I'm making a script to move files of certain type from folder and its subfolders on `P:\` to the created folder `P:\Move or delete`, so the user can see all the files before we delete them.

It needs to work even if they don't have any of the specified file types on their `P:\`, as there are about 110 people whom all have their own `P:\`.

The file types I need to move are: `mkv`, `bmp`, `img`, `jpg`, `ps`, `spiff`, `dib`, `jfif`, `pcx`, `psd`, `tif`, `eps`, `jpe`, `png`, `raw`, `tiff`, `gif`, `jpeg`, `aif`, `aiff`, `asf`, `asx`, `au`, `avi`, `flac`, `m3u`, `mid`, `midi`, `mov`, `mp1`, `mp2`, `mp3`, `mp4`, `mpa`, `mpe`, `mpeg`, `mpeg2`, `mpeg3`, `mpg`, `ogg`, `qt`, `qtw`, `ram`, `rm`, `rmi`, `mvb`, `snd`, `swf`, `vob`, `wav`, `wax`, `wma`, `wmv`, `wvx`, `aac`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
' Create Folder
Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Create a new folder
oFSO.CreateFolder "P:\Move or delete"
```

What's next?

Answer (score 1):

You need code for [traversing the folder tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/1630171) and a check to verify if a file matches your criteria. The latter is probably best done with a dictionary:

```
Set extensions = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
extensions.CompareMode = vbTextCompare  'case-insensitive
extensions.Add "mkv", True
extensions.Add "bmp", True
extensions.Add "img", True
...
```

That way you can simply look up an extension and move the file if you have a match:

```
For Each f In fldr.Files
  If extensions.Exists(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) Then
    f.Move "P:\Move or delete\"  '<-- note the trailing backslash!
  End If
Next
```

Since your destination folder is on the same drive that you're searching for files, you need to make sure that the folder is excluded from traversal.