# VBS - find oldest file in subfolders and move

Tags: vbscript, move, subdirectory

I am preparing script that should check several subfolders and move file for processing based on FIFO to work dir.

My (very short, amateur) code looks like this now.

```
Dim srcPath,trgtPath,objFile,totalFiles,fso

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
srcPath = "C:\terms\"

Set srcFolder = fso.GetFolder(srcPath)
trgtPath = "C:\AutoTerm\Temp"

If fso.GetFolder(srcPath).Files.Count < 1 Then
Wscript.Quit
End If

If fso.GetFolder(trgtPath).Files.Count => 1 Then
Wscript.Quit
End If


Dim oldestFile, oldestDate
For Each objFile In srcPath.Files
If oldestFile = "" Then
Set oldestFile = objFile
Else
If objFile.DateLastModified < oldestFile.DateLastModified Then
Set oldestFile = objFile
End If
End If
Next

oldestFile.Move trgtPath & "\" & oldestFile.Name

Wscript.Quit
```

I need this script to search all subfolders in trgtPath (c:\terms) and move only 1 oldest file to trgtPath. I tried

```
 Set Subfldr = srcPath.Subfolders
```

But it does not work, always asks for "object" and same result is when I tried to change For Each to folder and srcPath.Subfolders.

If you can please help me, I would be really grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: srcPath is a string, so it has no .Subfolders property. There is no shortage of VBScript sample code for recursive dir walkers on the net/ here - just look on the right for *Related*. E.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/603855 . Do some research and come back when you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`srcPath` is a string. `srcFolder` is your Folder object. Use `srcFolder.Files` instead.

Comment: Thank you, great! It works now. I am sorry, but I am real newbie and learning on the way.

Comment: It's no problem. That's why this site exists.