# windows explorer find and replace

Tags: vbscript

Found a nice piece of vbScript code on SuperUser that can function like find and replace in Office to locate and change characters/words in a folder to mass edit them to your liking.  I was wondering if this code could be expanded upon to call any and all sub folders under the root target folder?

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder("c:\test\")

For Each File In Folder.Files
    sNewFile = File.Name
    sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile,"_"," ")
    if (sNewFile<>File.Name) then 
        File.Move(File.ParentFolder+"\"+sNewFile)
    end if

Next
```

https://superuser.com/questions/197380/how-do-i-find-and-replace-a-character-in-filenames-in-windows-7-using-explorer

Comment: Yes you can, you can create a recursive function to navigate to all subfolders and from that call your `For Each` loop to change the files.

Comment: How exactly would you do that? Sorry not a coder but very much appreciate the help your giving.

Comment: You can research on the already asked questions, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/6352151)

Comment: to give you an example how easy this is in Ruby in one line: `Dir['*/**/*'].each {|f| File.rename(f, File.join(File.dirname(f),File.basename(f.gsub('_', ''))))}`