# VBScript to copy 720p 60fps MP4 files

Tags: video, vbscript

I'm trying to write a script that will copy mp4 files to specific folders based on their frame height or frame rate.  This is the code I have now that works but this just copies all MP4 files in a folder and subfolders to a destination folder.

How do I take it a step further and separate the files based on the frame height (720 for 720p files and 1080 for 1080i files)?

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objSTR, objMP4dest, objXCHANGEdest, objMP4ext, objXCHANGEext, obj720dest, obj1080dest
Dim objFILE, objFILE2, Folder, SubFolder

objSTR = "C:\Users\RMalone.SEC\Videos\MP4 Transfer Test\" 'Folder to search through
objMP4dest = "C:\Users\RMalone.SEC\Videos\MP4 Destination\" 'Folder I want mp4 files to copy to
obj720dest = "C:\Users\RMalone.SEC\Videos\MP4 Destination\720p 60fps\"
'Folder for 720p 60fps files
obj1080dest = "C:\Users\RMalone.SEC\Videos\MP4 Destination\1080 30fps"
'Folder for 1080i 30fps files
objXCHANGEdest = "C:\Users\RMalone.SEC\Videos\Finished\" 'Folder I want xchange files to copy to
objMP4ext = "mp4"
objXCHANGEext = "xchange"

For Each objFILE in objFSO.GetFolder(objSTR).Files
    If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFILE.Path) = objMP4ext Then
        objFILE.Copy objMP4dest
    End If
Next

For Each objFILE in objFSO.GetFolder(objSTR).Files
    If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFILE.Path) = objXCHANGEext Then
        objFILE.Copy objXCHANGEdest
    End If
Next

Call srchSUBFOLD(objFSO.GetFolder(objSTR))

Function srchSUBFOLD(Folder)
    For Each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        For Each objFILE in objFSO.GetFolder(SubFolder.Path).Files
            If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFILE.Path) = objMP4ext Then
                objFILE.Copy objMP4dest
            End If
        Next
        Call srchSUBFOLD(SubFolder)
    Next
End Function

Function srchSUBFOLD(Folder)
    For Each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        For Each objFILE in objFSO.GetFolder(SubFolder.Path).Files
            If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFILE.Path) = objXCHANGEext Then
                objFILE.Copy objXCHANGEdest
            End If
        Next
        Call srchSUBFOLD(SubFolder)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame height is stored in the files' extended properties. You can access the value like this:

```
dirname = "C:\your\video\folder"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set ns  = app.Namespace(dirname)

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(dirname)
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "mp4" Then
        fheight = ns.GetDetailsOf(ns.ParseName(f.Name), 283)
        Select Case fheight
            Case "720"  : 'copy to one location
            Case "1080" : 'copy to other location
            Case Else   : WScript.Echo "Unknown frame height " & fheight & _
                          " for file " & f.Name & "."
        End Select
    End If
Next
```

You can identify the names and index numbers of extended properties like this:

```
dirname = "C:\your\video\folder"

Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set ns  = app.Namespace(dirname)

For i=0 To 300
    WScript.Echo i & vbTab & ns.GetDetailsOf(ns.Items, i)
Next
```

**Note:** Run the script with `cscript.exe`, so you don't get 300 popups!

Comment: This worked! Thank you!! How would  make this work for subfolders as well?

Comment: @RandallMalone Use [folder recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14965606/1630171).