# Recursive file renaming

Tags: vbscript

For legal reasons, my company is trying to scrub a specific acronym from our entire file system. A search returns nearly 30,000 instances of said acronym. I have written the following VBS using the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950475/recursively-access-subfolder-files-inside-a-folder) to attempt to make the process recursive. Unfortunately, I failed to properly implement it.

I am getting an "Invalid procedure call or argument" error in line 3.
If I edit it to reference the root folder, I instead get an Object required: 'File' error in line 18.

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder("<folderpath>")

TraverseFolders objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

Function TraverseFolders(fldr)
    For Each File In Folder.SubFolders
        sNewFile = File.Name
        sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile, "old acronym", "new acronym")
        If (sNewFile <> File.Name) Then
            File.Move(File.ParentFolder + "\" + sNewFile)
        End If
    Next

    For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
        TraverseFolders sf
    Next
    sNewFile = File.Name
    sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile, "old acronym", "new acronym")
    If (sNewFile <> File.Name) Then
        File.Move(File.ParentFolder + "\" + sNewFile)
    End If
End Function
```

What am I missing to make this work recursively?

Comment: `For Each File In Folder.SubFolders` is wrong.

Comment: What is right, then?

Comment: probably needs to be `For Each File In fldr.Files`

Comment: And remove the file renaming code after the second loop. Also, `strPath` in your code is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, it was the strpath

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who stumble here, the issue was defining the strPath and referencing Folder instead of fldr.
Here is the correct code:

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set strPath = objFSO.GetFolder("<folder path>")
'setting the strPath instead of the unused Folder'
TraverseFolders objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

Function TraverseFolders(fldr)

  For Each File In fldr.Files
  'Referencing fldr instead of the unused Folder'
    sNewFile = File.Name
    sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile,"old acronym","new acronym")
    if (sNewFile<>File.Name) then 
        File.Move(File.ParentFolder+"\"+sNewFile)
    end if

Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    TraverseFolders sf  
    'Removed unnecessary code duplicate'
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: You are doing `objFSO.GetFolder` twice. `Set strPath = objFSO.GetFolder("<folder path>")` should simply be `strPath ="<folder path>"`